# SAPUI5 - Master view on sub-page

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to create a site where only the detail view is displayed on the front page

```
var splitApp = new sap.m.SplitApp("comboTestApp", {
        mode: sap.m.SplitAppMode.HideMode
    });
```

but where both the Master and the Detail view are displayed on every sub page

```
var splitApp = new sap.m.SplitApp("comboTestApp", {
        mode: sap.m.SplitAppMode.ShowHideMode
    });
```

My approach so far is to define a global variable and so something like this:

```
var splitApp;

sap.ui.jsview("view.App", {

    [...]

    splitApp = new sap.m.SplitApp("comboTestApp", {
        mode: sap.m.SplitAppMode.HideMode
    });

    [...]

    return splitApp;
}

});

showMasterView = function () {
    splitApp.setMode(sap.m.SplitAppMode.ShowHideMode);
}
hideMasterView = function () {
    splitApp.setMode(sap.m.SplitAppMode.HideMode);
}
```

Obviously this solution is pretty bad and creates quite a lot of problems. 
So I guess there is a pretty elegant solution to this but I can´t find an OPENUI5/SAPUI5 example which contains routing and where you have a starting page without a Master view and then sub pages where the Master is shown.

Any help on this topic is highly appreciated! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I got you right you want an application which has a single page as landing page and on navigating deeper in your application you want to have a splitted app. What I did to do this is to have a [sap.m.App](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.App.html) for top level routing. Once you go deeper in your application you have a view which returns a [sap.m.SplitContainer](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.SplitContainer.html).

Comment: I 100% agree with the comment from Tim Gerlach. As far as good examples about developing apps please have a look at: https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/8b49fc198bf04b2d9800fc37fecbb218.html

Cheers